# Java Random() rounding off

Tags: java, random

I'm using Java's Random to generate random numbers: 1.0, 1.1 - 10

```
Random random = new Random();
return (double) ((random.nextInt(91) + 10) / 10.0);
```

When I printed a lot of these numbers (2000), I noticed 1.0 and 10 are significant less printed than all others (repeated 20 times, happened every time). Most likely because 0.95-0.99 and 10.01-10.04 aren't generated.

Now I have read a lot of threads about this, but it still leaves me to the following question:

If these numbers would represent grades for example, you can't get lower than a 1 and higher than a 10 here, would it be legit to extend the range from 0.95 up to 10.04?

```
Random random = new Random();
return Double.valueOf((1005-95) / 100);
```

Comment: how many numbers did you generate?

Comment: oh sorry, i generated 2000 numbers and repeated it at least 20 times. that's why i noticed

Comment: and you want to generate number between 1.1 and 10 ?

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to do

Comment: what is your purpose of the second code block?

Comment: found the double.valueOf in other threads. Thought if I use that instead and give a min and max I extend the results from 1.0 to 10 to 0.95 to 10.04 so the chance of getting 1.0 and 10 are the some for hitting 2 (from 1.95 till 2.04)

Comment: According to [this](https://ideone.com/LWow3c), 1.0 and 10.0 are generated with approximately the same frequency as the others.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random value between 1.1 and 10 use the following code:

```
  double min = 1.1d;
  double max = 10d;
  Random r = new Random();
  double value = min + (max - min) * r.nextDouble();
```

Afterwarsds you can use `Math.floor(value)` too round your result

Answer (score 1):

This premise

> Most likely because 0.95-0.99 and 10.01-10.04 aren't
>   generated.

is wrong. You generate random ints from 10 inclusive to 100 inclusive. Lower fractions and rounding of values does not play into it. Random nextInt is random in the interval; the end cases is not discriminated against.

I think your method

```
Random random = new Random();
return (double) ((random.nextInt(91) + 10) / 10.0);
```

Looks correct. I would suggest measuring the anomaly you are experiencing, maybe it is a human bias from when you are merely looking at the output.

Here is some code that measures the actual random generation of the 91 values. It is before the conversion to double which is not ideal.(but I do not see how dividing by 10 does anything else than map values as 10 -> 1.0, 11 -> 1.1 ... 99 -> 9.9 and 100 -> 10.0. A measure of the final result would of course be more desirable)

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] measure = new int[101];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        int number =  (random.nextInt(91) + 10);
        measure[number]++;         

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + " count: " + measure[i]);

    }
```

Looking at the results from that code the 10 and 100 values seem to come up as often as any other.

Comment: so you're saying it's just random that I had these results 20 times in a row? If I would run it 100 times more i would have the same with 2.1 or 8.5?

Comment: Check my edit; it might miss the point a bit if you are worried about the division and mapping from integer to double. We shouldn't underestimate the 'interpretation' humans do when looking at data. I am not convinced your initial method is wrong!

Comment: hilarious how the results show me that 10 even has been generated most this time... gues you can't 'beat' random...